# Convert non-standard date format to date in R

Tags: r, date

I have dates in the format 01jan2000 (without a space or any separator) and need to convert this to a date in R so I can calculate ages. I have tried both

```
mydata$censor_date <- as.Date(mydata$censor_date, "%d-%b-%Y")
```

and

```
mydata$censor_date <- as.Date(mydata$censor_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

But I only get NAs. I can do this in Excel, but would prefer to have one script to run rather than switch between programmes. The exact format of the date isn't important, as long as I can use R to calculate ages.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `as.Date(mydata$censor_date, "%d%b%Y")` also not work?

Comment: also `library(lubridate)   dmy(mydata$censor_date)`

Comment: Didn't think to try that! Thanks Batanichek that does work!

Comment: someone post an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have date in "01jan2000" format you  not need "-" in format.

Try

```
as.Date(mydata$censor_date, "%d%b%Y")
```